# How to maintain common code for lite & premium version in android

Tags: android

I am developing android application where I need to maintain two versions on play store(Lite & Gold). Both applications functionality are same but UI theme is different. So I just want to know that what are the ways we can manage common code & drawables for both application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Android Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects):

> An Android library project is a development project that holds shared
>   Android source code and resources. Other Android application projects
>   can reference the library project and, at build time, include its
>   compiled sources in their .apk files. Multiple application projects
>   can reference the same library project and any single application
>   project can reference multiple library projects.

Resource folder and activity classes can be both in the library or in the main project. All things that are common in the projects can go to the library project. The library project must also contain the "default" resources. This is needed for the source code to compile. However, these resources would be over written by the ones in the main project.

The main project would only contain the manifest (different package name and probably themes) and specific resources.

Comment: As the above poster said, use Android libraries.

Set your current project as a library, create 2 new projects, a free and paid project, and then add your main library to those projects. Don't forget to change the package names and add the manifest! As soon as you change your main project to a library, the manifest file is redundant and it uses the one from the free/paid packages instead.

Comment: What about resource folder? Where I need to manage it? And what about activity classes, this classes are also in library?

Answer (score 1):

Make your project library and create two projects with separate themes and styles.